# Two Linux Mint 16 systems Skyping--one can see both parties on webcam, the other can see neither

Tags: linux-mint, skype, webcam

I installed Linux Mint 16 32-bit edition on my netbook and a friend's laptop.  When we Skype, I can see her live image, and I can see my own live image, so everything looks and sounds right on my end.  On her end, she can see neither of our webcam images--just a static avatar for me, and a black box where her webcam image should be.  Stranger still, in the Skype options under Video Devices, it says "no devices found"!  That's really funny to me, because if Skype can't find a webcam device, how is it broadcasting from it to me over the internet?  But more to the point, how can we get it so she can see me?

Just FYI, Skyping with her from a Windows machine also works on my end but not hers: again, I can see both her and I, and she can see neither of us.

Comment: Make her use a different distro?

Comment: @OneOfOne, I suppose that's always an option, but a little outside of what I meant.  I just installed the same OS and software, so why this strange thing where both our webcams obviously are actively working, yet she can't see either of them?  How can I diagnose and fix this issue, *without* having to install another OS?